# Two things that can be confused

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The title says it all. What two things can be confused?

(Just look around, look closely at this question...)

Comment: Are there not many possible good answers to this question? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are missing something alright.

Comment: This question is too generic.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not the answer, but I can't help myself:

[Eco funds](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/05/18/business/tesla-esg-index-musk.html) [ = confused ]

Comment: Explain the [visual] tag.

Answer (score -1):

> people can be confused about things

and

> homonyms (among other things) can be confused for each other by people

Comment: How does this fit the [visual] tag?